# How to create a new-mailuser

Tags: powershell

I would like to create a new user on exchange, but I can't. The user uses their external address. Here is what I did and the following error message.

```
$password = "DsDggfde4563!"
$Name = "IAM, Test"

New-MailUser -Name $Name -MicrosoftOnlineServicesID "iamtest@test.com" -ExternalEmailAddress "iamtest@test.com" -Password (ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force) -OrganizationalUnit "OU=Users,DC=test,DC=com"
```

Write-ErrorMessage : |Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.ThrowTerminatingErrorException|Organizational unit "test.com/Users" was
not found. Please make sure you have typed it correctly.

Comment: The eror message is quite clear... Make sure you enter the correct DistinghuishedName (GUID, CanonicalName or Name) of an **existing** OU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying the default users container then I think you are using the wrong -OrganizationalUnit.
The default Users is a CN.

check the below code:

```
$password = "DsDggfde4563!"
$Name = "IAM, Test"

New-MailUser -Name $Name -MicrosoftOnlineServicesID "iamtest@test.com" -ExternalEmailAddress "iamtest@test.com" -Password (ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force) -OrganizationalUnit "CN=Users,DC=test,DC=com"
```